Dart FFI with MATLAB
I'm trying to make a flutter apllication read a 1xN matrix from a .mat file then process this data with a standalone matlab application so when I tried to acheive that the application just loses the connection at some point
MATLAB function:
function results = singleRVAnalysis(sample, numBins)
    % SINGLE_RVANALYSIS Analyzes a single random variable sample
    %
    % Inputs:
    %   sample - Array of sample data
    %   numBins - Number of bins for histogram (default: 50)
    %
    % Outputs:
    %   results - A structure containing PDF, CDF, mean, variance, and third moment

    if nargin < 2
        numBins = 50; 
    end

    edges = linspace(min(sample), max(sample), numBins + 1);

    counts = histcounts(sample, edges);
    binWidth = diff(edges);
    pdf = counts / (sum(counts) * binWidth(1)); 
    cdf = cumsum(pdf) * binWidth(1); 

    binCenters = edges(1:end-1) + diff(edges) / 2;
    meanValue = sum(binCenters .* pdf * binWidth(1));
    varianceValue = sum(((binCenters - meanValue).^2) .* pdf * binWidth(1));
    thirdMomentValue = sum(((binCenters - meanValue).^3) .* pdf * binWidth(1));

    results = struct;
    results.PDF = pdf;
    results.CDF = cdf;
    results.Mean = meanValue;
    results.Variance = varianceValue;
    results.ThirdMoment = thirdMomentValue;
    results.Edges = edges;
end


Flutter Code:
import 'dart:ffi';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:ffi/ffi.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:file_picker/file_picker.dart';

const String dllPath = 'lib\\SingleRVAnalysis\\SingleRVAnalysisLib.dll';

final DynamicLibrary singleRVAnalysisLib = DynamicLibrary.open(dllPath);

final class Results extends Struct {
  external Pointer<Double> pdf;
  external Pointer<Double> cdf;
  @Double()
  external double mean;
  @Double()
  external double variance;
  @Double()
  external double thirdMoment;
  external Pointer<Double> edges;
  @Int32()
  external int binCount;
}

typedef SingleRVAnalysisNative = Results Function(
    Pointer<Double>, Int32, Int32);
typedef SingleRVAnalysisDart = Results Function(Pointer<Double>, int, int);

final singleRVAnalysis = singleRVAnalysisLib.lookupFunction<
    SingleRVAnalysisNative, SingleRVAnalysisDart>('mlxSingleRVAnalysis');

enum FileProcessStatus { idle, processing, completed, failed }

class FileProcessCubit extends Cubit<Map<String, dynamic>> {
  FileProcessCubit() : super({'status': FileProcessStatus.idle, 'file': null});

  void pickFile() async {
    try {
      final result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles();

      if (result != null && result.files.single.path != null) {
        emit({
          'status': FileProcessStatus.processing,
          'file': result.files.single,
        });
        await processFile(result.files.single);
      } else {
        emit({
          'status': FileProcessStatus.failed,
          'error': 'No file selected',
        });
      }
    } catch (e) {
      emit({
        'status': FileProcessStatus.failed,
        'error': 'File picking error: $e',
      });
    }
  }

  Future<void> processFile(PlatformFile file) async {
    final filePath = file.path;

    if (filePath == null) {
      emit({
        'status': FileProcessStatus.failed,
        'error': 'No file path available',
      });
      return;
    }

    try {
      final content = await File(filePath).readAsBytes();

      if (content.isEmpty) {
        throw Exception('The file is empty.');
      }

      final List<double> sample = content
          .toString()
          .replaceAll(RegExp(r'[^\d\.\-eE, ]'), '')
          .split(RegExp(r'[,\s]+'))
          .where((e) => e.isNotEmpty)
          .map((e) => double.tryParse(e) ?? 0.0)
          .toList();

      if (sample.isEmpty) {
        throw Exception('Sample array is empty.');
      }

      const int numBins = 50;
      final Pointer<Double> samplePointer = listToPointerDouble(sample);
      final result = singleRVAnalysis(samplePointer, sample.length, numBins);

      try {
        final pdf = result.pdf.asTypedList(numBins).toList();
        final cdf = result.cdf.asTypedList(numBins).toList();
        final mean = result.mean;
        final variance = result.variance;
        final thirdMoment = result.thirdMoment;

        emit({
          'status': FileProcessStatus.completed,
          'mean': mean,
          'variance': variance,
          'thirdMoment': thirdMoment,
          'pdf': pdf,
          'cdf': cdf,
        });
      } catch (e) {
        emit({
          'status': FileProcessStatus.failed,
          'error': 'Error during DLL processing: $e',
        });
      } finally {
        calloc.free(samplePointer);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      emit({
        'status': FileProcessStatus.failed,
        'error': 'Processing failed: $e',
      });
    }
  }

  void reset() {
    emit({'status': FileProcessStatus.idle, 'file': null});
  }
}

Pointer<Double> listToPointerDouble(List<double> sample) {
  final Pointer<Double> pointer =
      calloc.allocate<Double>(sample.length, alignment: 8);

  for (int i = 0; i < sample.length; i++) {
    pointer[i] = sample[i];
  }

  return pointer;
}


It should allocate the sample pointer then pass it to the function to return the results but It crashes at some point in allocating the samplePointer

What error do you get, and where?

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

Nothing comes in the logs it just crashes but when I trued to reduce the sample size it worked just fine but got another error where the results pointers are not aligned

Try modify your dart code like that:
Pointer<Double> listToPointerDouble(List<double> sample) {
  final Pointer<Double> pointer =
      calloc.allocate<Double>(sample.length, alignment: 8);
  final nativeSamples = pointer.asTypedList(sample.length);
  nativeSamples.setAll(0, sample);
  return pointer.cast<Double>();
}

Don`t forget to free your memory after is unnecessary.
calloc.free(pointer);


Thanks but it still crashes
